How to compile a python script to a Linux binary on a Windows machine (with installed dependencies)?
I want to compile a Python script into a Linux standalone binary (with all dependencies ofc) directly on a Windows machine.
The reason is that I want to test said binary on a Linux VM without installing the dependencies on it or create another VM specifically for this one task.
What should I do?
I tried compiling the Python code into a Windows executable, worked like a charm, tried using said executable to Linux VM and obviously it didn't work.
Read this, which is quite the opposite of this case, but thought that maybe there exists another workaround for it.
